# Firestore transaction billing rules

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I'm new in Android and Firestore. Im currently making an app that uses Cloud Firestore. In my transaction I have one read (transaction.get()) and one write (transaction.set()) operation. I've noticed that in usage tab in Firebase Console, this transaction increments read counter by 1, but write counter increments by 2. I have removed transaction.set operation for testing, and with transaction.get operation only, this whole transaction still increments write counter by 1. Is it normal? Are those normal rules for billing transactions in firestore? I don't know if it matters that reading and writing is done to different files in Cloud Firestore.

```
db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Object>() {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(carReference);
          .
          .
          .

        transaction.set(pointReference, point);
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations), it is mentioned that: For writes, each set() or update() operation counts a single write. Thus, the counter should not increase having deleted the set(). Do you by any chance an update in a different part of the code?

Comment: There is no other update() or set() operation in any part of my code. When I leave the body of transaction empty, and run the app, the counter in Firebase console doesn't increase, but if I only put there "DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(carReference);" it counts as one read and one write. I know that it should't.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue, as when I perform a get() operation, only the reads are increased and not the writes in the Firestore Usage Tab. I would recommend you to contact the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact), as the issue could be related to your project and the team could investigate it further.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations), You are charged for each document read, write, and delete that you perform with Cloud Firestore.

In your case, I am not able to see why the write is incremented by 2 the first time you write. Maybe you are writing something else in the code.

But regarding the reads, it's an [expected behavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations) because when you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. And in your case, as you are setting, so the second time, the read is incremented by 1.